# How can I use ~(이)ㄹ랑 (or should I avoid it)? Is it only used for people?

Tags: particle

> 너**일랑** 참견하지 말고 저리 가 있거라. –  you stop interfering and go away!

What meaning does this particle add? Is it just making the tone more aggressive, and if so, how aggressive is it? What would be some other examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. What meaning does this particle add?

It adds an emphasis on the subject. The main difference between "너일랑 참견하지 말고 저리 가 있거라." and "너는 참견하지 말고 저리 가 있거라." is the former emphasizes the subject *너* as if your (너의) interference (참견) were particularly disliked.

2. Is it just making the tone more aggressive, and if so, how aggressive is it?

No. It all depends on context and it doesn't always make the tone more aggressive. The example sentence you quoted can only be used in argument and the sentence itself is impolite. However, it could also be used in polite context. For example:

> 일**일랑**은 걱정을 말고 푹 쉬다 오세요. Don't worry about the work and take a good rest. (You don't have to particularly worry about the work and take a good rest.)

Here, '일랑' is also used to emphasize 'work' that shouldn't be particularly worried about.

It's not easy to understand its meaning and nuance. But it is broadly used when you give advice.

> 술**일랑** 마실 생각하지 마라. Don't even think about drinking an alcohol.
>
> 그와 결혼할 생각**일랑** 하지 마라. Don't even think about marrying him.
>
> 술먹고 운전할 생각**일랑** 하지 마라. Don't even think about driving after drinking.

~ 생각일랑 하지 마라 (마세요) is a useful idiomatic expression when you give advice to your friends (or colleagues).

3. Should I avoid it?

No. If you use it in the right context, you will surprise native Korean speakers and they would respond "와, 한국말 되게 잘 하시네요. Wow, your Korean is excellent."

4. Is it only used for people?

Not really as indicated above.

Comment: Your answer is better than mine. +1

Answer (score 1):

일랑 is a colloquial 보조사(補助詞 - Auxiliary) that is attached after a 체언(體言 - 'Uninflected Word'/'Substantive') that has a Supporting Consonant. When used, it indicates an intent to give some advice on the indicated subject of the sentence. It is considered to have a more aggressive tone, as it is frequently used in serious conversations.

Comment: What do you mean by "a Supporting Consonant"?

Comment: @gaeguri 받침. It is also the Final Consonant; using that word itself as an example, the Consonants in question would be ㄷ and ㅁ.

Comment: But in 너일랑, 너 has no 받침. This contradicts your answer, doesn't it?

Comment: @파울울 And, taking a closer look, my own example contradicts it. Should've proof read it better. ㅠㅠ. The official definition that I've found requires 받침. I'll go back to make sure.

Comment: Yeah, it requires 받침, which makes both my example and his invalid. I'll just remove my example.